# How to save a table exactly as it is (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a code that creates a table named "swh_sa" from various NC files. The problem is that this code can only be ran once to produce this table. If it is ran more than once, then it will result in an error. So, I am interested in saving this table exactly as it is so I can bring it up in others codes I'm writing. The picture below is the data table I want to save.
[image]

I attempted to do this by saving it as a csv file using the line:

```
swh_sa.to_csv(r"C:\\Users\\xil15102\\Documents\\swh_sa.csv")
```

However, I found that the time column of the file has been saved in an incorrect format (see picture below). Is there a way I could save this table while keeping the same format?
[image]

Comment: You could try `df.to_pickle('your_file.pkl')` and then load it with `pd.read_pickle('your_file.pkl')`. That will preserve dtypes, which I'm guessing might lead to this issue upon reading/writing.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] and avoid screenshots. Without some code, we won't able to figure out what exactly the issue is here.

Comment: As above; additionally ensure your (date in this example) data types are as expected.  In other words, your date is a datetime type, not str.